# Conditionally count values in array of arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
array('0'=> 
            array(
           'fromDate' =>2007,
           'toDate' => 2008,
           'value' => 7)
      '1'=>
            array(
            'fromDate' =>2010,
            'toDate' => ,
            'value' => 3)
      '2'=>
            array(
            'fromDate' => 2007,
            'toDate' => ,  
            'value' => 4))
```

I want to count 'value', add them up grouped by 'fromDate' like this:

```
array('0' =>
             array(
             'fromDate' => 2007,
             'sum' => 2)
      '1' =>
            array(
            'fromDate' => 2010,
            'sum' => 1))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what your requirement is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myData = array('0'=>
            array(
           'fromDate' =>2007,
           'toDate' => 2008,
           'value' => 7),
      '1'=>
            array(
            'fromDate' =>2010,
            'toDate' => NULL,
            'value' => 3),
      '2'=>
            array(
            'fromDate' => 2007,
            'toDate' => NULL,
            'value' => 4)
);

$counts = array_reduce(
    $myData,
    function ($counter, $entry) {
        if (!isset($counter[$entry['fromDate']])) {
            $counter[$entry['fromDate']] = array(
                'fromDate' => $entry['fromDate'],
                'sum' => 1
            );
        } else {
            $counter[$entry['fromDate']]['sum']++;
        }
        return $counter;
    },
    array()
);

var_dump($counts);
```

Comment: +1. Not a fan of `array_reduce()` but this answer makes good use of it :)

Comment: Thanks @Mark Baker! Now I need to understand why it works like a charm :) Any tips on where to best learn everything regarding arrays?

Comment: Best place to start (as always) is the php docs for array functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php); and the relevant pages on closures (http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for using closures in callbacks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many arrays with "fromDate" e.g. 2007 you have:

```
function countByFromDate($array) {
  $result = array();
  foreach($array as $item) {
    $fromDate = $item['fromDate'];
    if (!isset($result[$fromDate])) {
      $result[$fromDate] = array('fromDate' => $fromDate, 'sum' => 0);  
    }
    $result[$fromDate]['sum']++;
  }

  return $result; 
}
```